# Not being able to ssh despite using correct password

Tags: macos, unix, ssh

I'm trying to follow up with this tutorial
https://samsclass.info/128/proj/p2xipre.htm

I installed 
`brew install libimobiledevice`
Then I did `iproxy 2222 22`
Everything works as expected; until I have to `ssh -p 2222 root@localhost`

I get `permission denied, try again` everytime I put the password; I even changed and made sure using `passwd` command. No clue why it's acting up.

Comment: Is your device jailbroken?

Comment: @l'L'l yes it is.

Comment: One more thought, have you tried the default root password "alpine"?

Comment: Wow, I've been trying toor1 all this time. Alpine instantly worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the tutorial you were following had some confusion about the password. Usually when something like this happens to me on a jailbroken device I go back and try to `ssh` with the default username and password:

```
username: root
password: alpine
```

> Nine times out of ten the password is set to the default, so try there
>   first.